# How can I prevent planeswalkers from organizing into an army?

Tags: magic, universe

A demigods is a human who is born with a divine spark. When this spark is activated, the individual becomes a being with incredible power. It grants them a number of abilities, including immortality, near-invulnerability to mortal weapons, robust healing factor, and vast magical power. However, their most important power is the ability to travel between different realms in the multiverse when normal humans are unable to do so. This divine spark is part of an individual's soul, and is found at random among the population. Therefore, they are the equivalent of planeswalkers to the people of the multiverse, chosen by the gods to defend the various realms from outside threats (worlds ruled by demons, creatures from the space between realms, etc)

The demigods function as an organization that operate within a hidden realm only inhabited by their kind. This organization has the technology to locate children across the realms who possess the spark, which manifests at the age of puberty. When a child is found, demigods are dispatched to that realm to claim this child from their family. Through an ancient pact with humanity, the gods decreed that all children born with this spark are laid claimed to by the walkers in exchange for protection against evil forces. This is the only way that demigods replenish their numbers. This pact also prevents demigods from interfering with baseline humanity and civilization, except in specifically extreme circumstances that have to do in defending the realm from outside forces.

From a practical standpoint, it would make sense that this organization would promote close cooperation among their members. demigods would work in teams to battle threats when they arise. However, I want them to usually operate solo and alone for most major and minor threats to the realms. It should be very rare for demigods to operate together or be in one place at the same time outside of their base realm.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: This is similar to how a police force operates. These days they may go around in pairs rather than alone but large groups only appear when they have to cope with an actual incident. What keeps police from forming an army?

Comment: well, planeswalkers rather have the tasks of a commando unit than that of ordinary police, and commando units operate in teams. to make that behaviour reasonable, you must add a new constraint. like... "the force"!

Comment: Worth noting: the skill of battling something as a cohesive unit is *not* just randomly picked up by working solo.  If the walkers wish to take on major threats you're going to have to spend a substantial amount of effort explaining how they don't just fall apart like a house of cards in the face of an opponent worth organizing against.

Answer (score 7):

Just make the space which must be defended so large that no standing army could defend it all without spreading out to the point that each soldier stands alone.

In [Roger Zelazny's Amber chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber), the separate planes are laid out somewhat sequentially and some people can travel between them in a linear fashion by shifting from the current plane to one almost identical to it, on a spectrum between Amber and the Courts of Chaos.  This organization implied that although vast, the multi-verse has a fathomable scale.  Armies could march towards Amber or towards the Courts, and meet unavoidable resistance along the way.

But if you arrange your planes across three dimensions then the number of paths which lead towards any single destination expands exponentially with distance from that destination. There is no way to place a single army between your enemy and their goal because they can just go around the army through other dimensions and still reach where they want to go.

The only way to defend any location from within such an infinitely layered battleground would be to spread your warriors out like a net as thinly as possible in all directions, then have each warrior use their magic to watch for enemy movements across their current dimension and maybe a few adjacent ones as well.  Even then, it is possible that small groups of the enemy may get past to attack your home.

Answer (score 7):

## Planeswalker's powers interfere with each other

Maybe it is the nature of their magic.  Maybe it is a failsafe designed by the gods.  But whatever the case, the magical powers of multiple Planeswalkers do not mesh.  They work just fine alone, or even in conjunction with normal wizards or magical monsters.  But if two 'walkers are together on the same plane, each of their powers' are effectively halved.  Three in close proximity are only at about 30% of their normal respective strengths, and so on.  Even if they are not in the same plane, but in adjacent planes, they suffer a slight loss of power.

And that is just the normal scenario, if the Planeswalker's abilities or mindsets are opposed, then the drain can be even greater.

On the other hand, Planeswalkers with similar powers and a strong mental bond (lovers, siblings, or occasionally friends) can overcome or even work within the interference.  They will still never be at full strength, but two 'walkers at 80% power is much better than one alone.  Still, this is a rarity, these partnerships are one in a few thousand, and the ones that can sufficiently synchronize themselves to get back up to 80% power are the rarest of the rare.  For most it is more like 60%.

Comment: that is just my answers idea in more general, without "the force" as explanation.

Comment: @KGM no, it is not.  Your answer is that there is not enough energy.  My answer is that the abilities themselves interfere with each outer.  Yours could be overcome by finding ways to store up the power.

Comment: who says that the power can be stored? maybe any attempt to store up only a little "force" ends in a magical desaster...

Comment: There's a straightforward way to sum up this answer: the Law of Conservation of Ninjutsu(https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConservationOfNinjutsu)

Answer (score 2):

**A demigod is a human**

As such, they are prone to the influences of greed and such nasties as us mortals.

An unit sent to a different plane will be expected to be outside the direct influence of the organization for a prolonged period while they investigate and neutralize the threat. A deployed unit may use that time to conspire and go rogue. Why continue fighting evil when you can rule or enslave the lesser beings of the plane?

Once this rogue unit establishes control on the plane, it will take vast resources on part of the organization to uproot it and, given the scale of their power, may cause devastating, world-destroying, collateral damage.

The organization, probably having faced such incidents before, decided the cost of capture and removal of a rogue unit can be significantly minimized if they deployed a single demigod, or the minimal number necessary depending on the threat, rather than an army.

Answer (score 0):

This answer expands Henry Taylor's answer (which I consider very good).

The number of planes to defend might be infinite and usually a large organization as the one of the planewalkers' will need a significant portion of the staff to take care of the organizational and logistic side of things. Traveling from one plane to the other takes a fair amount of resources (even if it's an intrinsic ability of the planewalkers, they still need to eat and rest). And this bring me to my point:

### Efficiency

This organization must be efficient. And one planewalker is most of the times enough. They are strong enough to fight off the threats and wise enough (trained) to repel a bigger attack using the resources (people, magic) present on the plane. They only work together with each other when they need extra-planar resources to fight off the biggest of threats.

Answer (score -2):

## The planeswalkers best weapon is its magical powers.

## Magic is fueled by a renewable natural resource found everywhere, "the force".

However, while "the force" regenerates fast enough to fuel one planeswalkers spells,

## "the force" 's regeneration rate is not sufficient to fuel the spells of more than one planeswalker.

Thus, if multiple planeswalkers worked together, they would only have as much magical power as one.

## Therefore planeswalkers work solo on different threads

instead of working together on one at a time.

Comment: This answer might fade better if it weren’t so ***LOUD***.